# Modifying RSC bst file

Tags: bibtex

I'm using the RSC's (Royal Society of Chemistry) bst file to write my thesis. You can find this file [here](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/rsc/rsc.bst). But I would like to tweak it just a bit, to add for example the DOI at the end of each reference.

I discovered some interesting lines at the top of the file:

```
%% #0 turns off the display of the title for articles
%% #1 enables
FUNCTION {default.is.use.title} { #0 }

%% The number of names that force "et al." to be used
FUNCTION {default.etal.number} { #2 }

%% #0 turns off the display of the DOI for articles
%% #1 enables
FUNCTION {default.use.doi.all} { #0 }
```

So I changed the line about the doi to:

```
FUNCTION {default.use.doi.all} { #1 }
```

But nothing changed in my pdf output. I also tried to enable the display of titles, or change the etal number, but once again, I got nowhere. Can you please help me to figure it out ?

Comment: You don't need to edit the file to alter the control values: see the LaTeX `rsc` package which provides an interface for this. Once you set the right value, you'll need to run LaTeX/BibTeX/LaTeX/LaTeX to see the effect.

Comment: Yes, I know about that. But using this package messes with my setup of mciteplus or natbib. Suppose I just want to modify the bst file, how would I do it ?

Comment: You still don't need to modify the `.bst` (and if you do you need to copy and rename it). I'll post a 'raw' answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to alter the inclusion of DOIs is to use the `rsc` package

```
\usepackage[usedoi=true]{rsc}
```

This will send the appropriate setting through to the `rsc` bibliography style.

If you want to do things 'by hand', this can be done without copying and editing the `.bst` file by creating the 'special' reference by hand. Add an entry, either in a dedicated `.bib` file or in your general one for your document, reading

```
@Control{rsc-control,
  ctrl-use-title   =  "no",
  ctrl-use-doi-all =  "yes",
  ctrl-link-doi    =  "no",
  ctrl-etal-number =  "0",
}
```

where the settings are pretty obvious. Then add

```
\nocite{rsc-control}
```

right at the start of your document and include the appropriate `.bib` file in your `\bibliography` line.

This works by passing the settings to `rsc.bst` as a special citation, which is then picked up and used to alter the output without needing to make a separate renamed coped of `rsc.bst` for each possible option combination.

Comment: Thank you ! I read about the control citation in the rsc package's doc, but it just mentions it. Where did you find a more complete doc ? Are there more options ?

Comment: @Rififi The official interface is using the package: I quite deliberately don't document the mechanism (as I view it as 'internal' so subject to change). The idea itself comes originally from REVTeX and is used not only by `rsc` but several other BibTeX styles. There are no more options than the ones shown, which as I say map to the package interface in the natural way.

Comment: Ok, I got why there is no official doc. But maybe you could just add the control citation in the bst file of the package, for those with specific needs ?