# How to display titles in bibliography using rsc.bst?

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I'm trying to revise a submission to an RSC journal, and they want the bibliography to display the full title. I'm working in Overleaf using the provided RSC journal template for LaTeX.

I've tried the previously posted fix I found ([Modifying RSC bst file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/310878/modifying-rsc-bst-file)), which recommends using the rsc package to control it, but it gives me this when I use it:

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rsc/rsc.sty:41:
LaTeX Error: Option cla
sh for package natbib.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.41   \IfFileExists
                    {natmove.sty}{%
```

I also tried the "by hand" fix available there, but could not make that work. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: You could use the 'usetitle' option.

Comment: Can you describe how exactly?

Comment: Using th e`rsc` package with the option `usetitle` is what I would suggest. Could you please prepare an [MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/134144) that shows how you currently produce the bibliography?

Comment: As stated in my original question, I tried this fix using the rsc package and got the error I posted above. rsc seems to interfere with natbib in someway.

Comment: I fixed it by removing natbib as a package.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was solved by the OP in the comments without showing the original code that lead to the question.