# Including titles of papers cited using RSC format in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

Latex newbie here - I use Overleaf to generate my code, mostly.
I am currently drafting a paper that is to go to a RSC journal. However, this journal needs me to include the titles of the papers cited in the bibliography, which I don't know how to do.

I am using the standard RSC template hosted on Overleaf to prepare the manuscript.

https://www.overleaf.com/gallery/tagged/rsc#.VxDxA_lSiNs

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/426905/226

Answer (score 2):

The sample `.tex` files provided by RSC has `\bibliographystyle{rsc}` which by default leaves out the article titles. To get the titles back in, you'll have to load the `rsc` package with the `usetitle` option:

```
\usepackage[usetitle]{rsc}
```

Note that the sample `.tex` file also loads `natbib` in the preamble, and it'll clash with the `rsc` package. You'll therefore need to comment or delete the line `\usepackage[...]{natbib}` as well.